# How can I send my data to Kafka where data specific to a key goes to same partition only using KafkaSink in a Flink Streaming Job?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a requirement where I wish to send my data to same partition only if the data has same key.
For example:

{"field1": 33, "field2": 44, "field3": 55, "uniqueField": 1}

{"field1": 34, "field2": 45, "field3": 56, "uniqueField": 1}

{"field1": 35, "field2": 46, "field3": 57, "uniqueField": 1}

{"field1": 33, "field2": 44, "field3": 55, "uniqueField": 2}

{"field1": 33, "field2": 44, "field3": 55, "uniqueField": 2}

{"field1": 33, "field2": 44, "field3": 55, "uniqueField": 3}

So, I want data with uniqueField:1, goes to same partition, data with uniqueField:2 goes to same partition and data with uniqueField:3 goes to same partition.

So, eventually if the uniqueField is same, the partition for the data must also be same which means same uniqueField data must be same partition.

As of now, I am sending data to Kafka using KafkaSink as follows:

```
def getFlinkKafkaSink(jobConf: JobConfig, kafkaInfo: KafkaInfo): KafkaSink[String] = {

val properties: Properties = getProperties()
KafkaSink
      .builder[String]
      .setBootstrapServers(kafkaInfo.bootstrapServers)
      .setRecordSerializer(
        KafkaRecordSerializationSchema
          .builder()
          .setTopic(kafkaInfo.topics)
          .setValueSerializationSchema(new SimpleStringSchema())
          .build()
      )
      .setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
      .setKafkaProducerConfig(properties)
      .build()
}
```

Which is being called by main method:

```
 dataStream
          .sinkTo(FlinkExecutionEnviron.getFlinkKafkaSink(jobConf, kafkaInfo))
          .setParallelism(jobConf.FlinkProperties.producerParallelism)
          .name("Sink to Kafka Topic")
```

dataStream is basically DataStream[String]

From initial trials, i go to know that I need to implement KafkaRecordSerializationSchema somehow but could not get to that. I need to do this in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the data of the same `uniqueField` field to be sent to the same kafka partition, you only need to use the `keyBy` function to partition the `uniqueField` before the sink.

If you have other needs, or it is inconvenient to use the keyBy function, you can try using the `setPartitioner` method in `KafkaRecordSerializationSchema`. This method receives a FlinkKafkaPartitioner and can implement custom partitioning of kafka messages.

```
//assume your data type is Map[String, Int]
.setPartitioner(new FlinkKafkaPartitioner[Map[String, Int]]() {
  override def partition(record: Map[String, Int], key: Array[Byte], value: Array[Byte], targetTopic: String, partitions: Array[Int]): Int = {
    //This returns the partition number. This is a simple example. Suppose your topic has 30 partitions.
    record("uniqueField") % 30
  }
})
```

Comment: I would love to try the setPartitioner but i have few questions.
I am dealing with big data here and doing modulo to partition the data might skew the data(huge data in 1 partition and very less data in some other partition), isn't it? This way I will need to find some good way to select partition qand make sure load is balances equally among all partitions of kafka, right?

Comment: Regarding the keyBy function, I can do a keyBy based on a field in the data itself but I think the KafkaSink need a DataStream[String] and not a keyedStream to sink data to Kafka. So, how I am supposed to send keyedStream to sink? The current flow is kind of DataStream[SomeClass] ---> Serialization(created DataStream[String]) ---> dataStream.sinkTo(FlinkExecutionEnv.getFlinkKafkaSink(jobConf, kafkaInfo)) as shown in the description of this post above.

Comment: The `. setPartitioner()` method referenced by Shigure is how I would handle this. Coming up with the "right" way to partition the data to avoid skew isn't a Flink question, it's an application logic issue.